# Highcharts: Hide legend shape and show name

Tags: highcharts

how can i display title for dynamically added series and added y-Axis ? can i use legend and hide shapes from legend? what is better approach between legend and renderer

```
chart.renderer.text(text, 10, 10)
    .css({
        fontSize: '9px'
    }).add();
```

Comment: What do you mean "title"? A series has no "title" option, so I guess you mean "name" or something? Is the legends thing a separate question, or connected to the title/name thing?

Comment: Could you replicate your example as live demo, and explain your case in more details.

Comment: sorry for confusion.but stackoverflow didnt like my language.so i could not explain in details.all i want to add is series name in legend but hide the shape which usually in front of name. for now i am using renderer.text method. but i wanted to use legend since its better approach..here is my code http://jsfiddle.net/xutbe5qb/1/ as you can see. i am adding "volume" as a title of the axis. and legends are hidden.instead i want to enable legend. but only display "volume" meaning text part of legend..

Comment: Its not clear for me, could you attach any mockup / image how it should look like ?